# prove that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: calculus

Let: $f(x),x\in(0,+\infty)$ be a continuous and Bounded function,prove that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

is that right or wrong?
Can anybody give me some hints？

Comment: Not true. $f(x)=\sin x^2$, for example.

Comment: add $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$ exist and both are finites then it's true

Answer (score 1):

Take, for example: $$f(x) = \sin(\frac1x)$$

This function is continuous and bounded in $(0,+\infty)$. What happens when $x$ is near $0$?